# .NET Portability Analyzer woes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, portable-class-library

I'm running the .NET Portability Analyzer as part of an effort to get some old VB.net code to run under PCL.

When I run the analyzer, I end up with 4000 messages in my Error List, which makes finding actual Errors somewhat annoying.

Is there a way to clear these out? I can't find it!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the "Analyze Assembly Portability" command (in the Analyze menu) to analyze a .DLL instead of a project in the solution.  In that case it shouldn't add the errors to your error list.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the Messages tab / button in the Error List window, it will toggle whether those Message items are displayed in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the excel sheet / html / json  result generated during the analysis to find out the errors and the libraries and methods that are not supported. If it is n excel the second sheet will give you the results.